# Submit a single field within a form without using JavaScript

Tags: html

Lets say you have the following form

```
<form action='www.test.com/test1'>
<input type='text' name='input1'>
<input type='text' name='input2'>
<button type='button' href='www.test.com/test2'>Update</button>
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

You need to send data to the server with the Update button, but you want to submit to a different method than the form it is contained within.

You cant nest forms (obviously), you cannot create seperate forms and you cannot use JavaScript (to enable compatibility with older browsers).

It does not matter if anything else is submitted along with it, so long as test2 gets through to the server.

Is there any way to submit **input2** data to **test2**?

Comment: Name an _older browser_ which doesn't support `javascript`, please.

Comment: Even older browsers handle JavaScript just fine...

Comment: Its more to do with mobile tbh

Comment: Assuming that by "_different method_" you mean _different action_, where would the browser be redirected when the user presses the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try formaction?

```
<button type="submit" formaction="URL">
```

the url will be the new action, therefore 'www.test.com/test2'
The button must be type "submit" for this to work

Therefore your product will be:

```
<form action='www.test.com/test1'>
<input type='text' name='input1'>
<input type='text' name='input2'>
<button type='submit' formaction='www.test.com/test2'>Update</button>
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: As I said, *formaction* is HTML5. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp

Answer (score 1):

I'd say No.

That's possible in HTML5 with *formaction* attribute, but since you want to enable old browser, this can't be an answer.